# Qt memory management

Tags: c++, qt, memory

Consider the following snippet code:

```
1: QPushButton *p_Button = new QPushButton(this); 
2: QPushButton myButton(this);
```

**Line 1**: *this* is referred to QWidget, so p_Button is child of QWidget in my example: when QWidget dies (goes out the scope??) his destructor *deletes* p_Button from the heap and calls the destructor of p_Button.

**Line 2**: Same as Line 1, but does the destructor of QWidget *delete* myButton since its child is also myButton?

Please correct me if I stated something wrong and reply to my questions.

Comment: A better question for [here](http://www.qtcentre.org/forum.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and yes. If a `QObject` is not created by new, it must be destroyed before its parent. Otherwise, the parent will delete the child and the program may crash.

Qt has some good documentation on [object trees and ownership](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/objecttrees.html) that explains this.